# Как показать определённые блоки при выборе 2-х значений select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два select. В первом три option, во втором два. Есть две пачки блоков по 6 штук в каждой. Как при выборе значений в обоих select-ах выводить блоки соответсвующие значениям этих select-ов? Код ниже:

```css
.podbor {
  display: block;
}

.drop {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  border: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}

.price {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.price>div {
  display: none
}

.blocks {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.blocks>div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="podbor">
  Для
  <select class="drop" id="people">
    <option>1-го</option>
    <option selected>2-х</option>
    <option>семьи</option>
  </select>
  на
  <select class="drop" id="days">
    <option>3 дня</option>
    <option selected>5 дней</option>
  </select>
  <div class="price">
    <div id="pr1-3">Цена для 1-го на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr1-5">Цена для для 1-го на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr2-3">Цена для 2-х на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr2-5">Цена для 2-х на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="prs-3">Цена для семьи на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="prs-5">Цена для семьи на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks">
  <div id="bl1-3">Содержимое блока для 1-го на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bl1-5">Содержимое блока для 1-го на 5 дней</div>
  <div id="bl2-3">Содержимое блока для 2-х на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bl2-5">Содержимое блока для 2-х на 5 дней</div>
  <div id="bls-3">Содержимое блока для семьи на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bls-5">Содержимое блока для семьи на 5 дней</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#people, #days").on("change", function() {
    $(".price div, .blocks div").hide();
    $("#pr" + $("#people").val() + '-' + $("#days").val()).show();
    $("#bl" + $("#people").val() + '-' + $("#days").val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.podbor {
  display: block;
}

.drop {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  border: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}

.price {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.price>div {
  display: none
}

.blocks {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.blocks>div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="podbor">
  Для
  <select class="drop" id="people">
    <option value="1">1-го</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2-х</option>
    <option value="s">семьи</option>
  </select>
  на
  <select class="drop" id="days">
    <option value="3">3 дня</option>
    <option value="5" selected>5 дней</option>
  </select>
  <div class="price">
    <div id="pr1-3">Цена для 1-го на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr1-5">Цена для для 1-го на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr2-3">Цена для 2-х на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="pr2-5">Цена для 2-х на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="prs-3">Цена для семьи на 3 дня ХХХХХХ</div>
    <div id="prs-5">Цена для семьи на 5 дней ХХХХХХ</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks">
  <div id="bl1-3">Содержимое блока для 1-го на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bl1-5">Содержимое блока для 1-го на 5 дней</div>
  <div id="bl2-3">Содержимое блока для 2-х на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bl2-5">Содержимое блока для 2-х на 5 дней</div>
  <div id="bls-3">Содержимое блока для семьи на 3 дня</div>
  <div id="bls-5">Содержимое блока для семьи на 5 дней</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое, за быстрый ответ и за помощь.

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы блоки показывалась сразу для значений по умолчанию? Т.е. по умолчанию выбраны для 2-х на 5 дней. И для этих значений div-ы цена и содержимое блока отображалась изначально, а не после выбора. Или это совсем другая задача?

Comment: @Newageman самое простое отображать блоки по умолчанию через css если ивестны значения по умолчанию - https://jsfiddle.net/dvfas8g7/
или через javascript/jquery, если значения по умолчанию не известны(если нужно, напишите пожалуйста)

Comment: Вот я затупил. Я именно то что вы предложили делал, но допустил ошибку и ничего не работало. А у вас всё верно. Ещё раз спасибо.